# How to include two jquery mobile version in oracle apex 4.2

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, oracle-apex

I have some problem while trying to include jquery mobile 1.2 in apex 4.2. Currently apex 4.2 bundled with jquery mobile 1.1.1 and i need to use newest version which support dialog and pop up with a simple way. But when i try to include this newest version. My page become so mess up just like being rendered twice by jquery 1.1.1 and 1.2 version. Every object appear twice. I've tried using this script:

```
<script>
var jqm120 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

but no luck . Please kindly give me a hint. Thanx alot.

Answer (score 2):

In **APEX 4.2** you have new substitution strings `#APEX_CSS#` and `#APEX_JAVASCRIPT#` in your page template. You can **remove them** if you want to use your own libraries. Removing these substitution strings will prevent the following code from being added into the page header (assuming the *Content Delivery Network* from the application attributes is set to *"None"*) :

```
/your_image_prefix/css/apex.min.css?v=4.2.0.00.27
/your_image_prefix/libraries/jquery-ui/1.8.22/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css

/your_image_prefix/libraries/apex/minified/desktop_all.min.js?v=4.2.0.00.27
/your_image_prefix/libraries/apex/minified/legacy.min.js?v=4.2.0.00.27

<script type="text/javascript">
var apex_img_dir = "/your_image_prefix/", htmldb_Img_Dir = apex_img_dir;
</script>
```

[image: Warning] **Warning** : you may have to include some of the removed files manually, as some APEX default functionnalities will be removed at the same time :/

For example :

- `apex.min.css?v=4.2.0.00.27` is needed for the developer bar to be displayed properly.
- `desktop_all.min.js?v=4.2.0.00.27` does not include only JQuery and JQuery UI but also all the apex JQuery core functions...
- `legacy.min.js?v=4.2.0.00.27` is defining some main apex Javascript functions (like `doSubmit()`, etc...).

**Unfortunately** APEX does not provide substitution string to remove only the JQuery libraries...

So a solution is to retrieve the default APEX files, then remove only the JQuery library code from them, and replace it with the newer library code...

It is the only solution I have found, even if of course a simpler solution would be to use `JQuery.noConflict` as you mentionned (to be honest I have not tried it), but it will load the library two times, making your page to load slower ?

**EDIT** :

Sorry, in your case, as you are using **JQuery mobile**, it should be something like :

```
/your_image_prefix/libraries/jquery-mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css
/your_image_prefix/themes/theme_50/css/4_2.css

/your_image_prefix/libraries/apex/minified/mobile_all.min.js?v=4.2.0.00.27
/your_image_prefix/libraries/jquery-mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js
/your_image_prefix/libraries/apex/minified/legacy.min.js?v=4.2.0.00.27

<script type="text/javascript">
var apex_img_dir = "/your_image_prefix/", htmldb_Img_Dir = apex_img_dir;
</script>
```

that will be removed from the template (you can check by yourself).

But the remarks still apply.

Comment: On the mark, and also [how Patrick Wolf suggests it (OTN thread of this SO question)](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2457440&tstart=0)!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery_1.7.1.js'></script>   
<script type='text/javascript'>  
 // In case you wonder why we pass the "true" parameter,
 // here is the explanation:
 //   - When you use jQuery.noConflict(), it deletes
 //     the "$" global variable.
 //   - When you use jQuery.noConflict(true), it also
 //     deletes the "jQuery" global variable.
 var $jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);  
</script>  
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery_1.2.1.js'></script>
```

And this way when you want something made with the new version of jquery instead of the `$` use `$jq`.

```
$jq('.selector').on('click', function(){  
    //do something  
});
```

Comment: i couldn't use that in dialog and pop up function, because you just need to call the class without using those $jq variable. my problem is all my object rendered twice. but the function is working fine.